# Move data from inside nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have inserted multiple documents in my Mongo database incorrectly. I have accidentally nested the data inside another data object:

```
{
  "_id": "5cdfda8ddc5cf00031fd3949",
  "payload": {
    "timestamp": "2019-05-18T10:12:29.896Z",
    "data": {
      "data": {
        "name": 10,
        "age": 10,
      }
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

I would like the document to not have the extra data object. So I would like it to look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5cdfda8ddc5cf00031fd3949",
  "payload": {
    "timestamp": "2019-05-18T10:12:29.896Z",
    "data": {
      "name": 10,
      "age": 10,

    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

Is there a way in Mongo for me to update all the documents that have 2 data objects to just have one like shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, you cannot do this with one database request. You have to loop over all documents programmatically, set the new data and update them in the database.

Comment: That is what i taught i would have to do just taught there may have been a easier way

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), which won't let you update in place, but you could use the [$out operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to write the results to a new collection, if that's an option.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      __v : 1,
      "payload.timestamp" : 1,
      "payload.data" : "$payload.data.data"
    },
  },
  {
    "$out": "newCollection"
  }
])
```

Or if you have a mixture of docs with correct format and docs with incorrect format, you can use the [$cond operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to determine the correct output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      __v : 1,
      "payload.timestamp" : 1,
      "payload.data" : {
        $cond: [
          { $ne : [ "$payload.data.data", undefined]},
          "$payload.data.data",
          "$payload.data"
        ]} 
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": "newCollection"
  }
])
```

Comment: Writing to another collection isnt really an option so i went with @mbuechmann suggest of looping over them and updating them

Comment: Great! You can click the checkmark beside their answer, to accept it so that the community knows the question is solved  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers